# Elasticsearch : What is recommended number of indices one can create?

Tags: elasticsearch

What is recommended number of indices one can create in elasticsearch ?
Is there any standard formula for this ?

I tried to create approx. 300 indices with approx 50 docs each. but it is failing.

Comment: It depends on so many factors, no one can answer that precisely. but 50 docs in an index is a really small amount (and waste of resources). you probably only need a single index for so few documents. You can also read this article which explains how to size your cluster: https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-many-shards-should-i-have-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster

Comment: While a primary shard can technically contain up to Integer.MAX_VALUE - 128 documents, the practical limit depends on your use case: the hardware you have, the size and complexity of your documents, how you index and query your documents, and your expected response times.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one type of entity, you should use ONE index, but you can divide it on several shards. Count of shards depends on your data and hardware.

Comment: It depends if the entity is time-based (like e.g. logs), in which cases time-based indices would be more appropriate (i.e. one index per day/week/month/year/etc).

Comment: my entity is not time based

Answer (score 0):

elasticsearch indices are virtual, at the end, your data is stored into Apache Lucene shards.

1 index can have many primary shards and replica shards (copy of primary shards).

50 indices can mean 50x3x2 => 300 shards.

shards are resources consuming:

- thread / CPU
- RAM to store cache + field-data + ordinal etc...

As anybody said, there is no a magic formula for this (same thing with any data software such as mysql, mongodb etc...), you must test, monitor (via `/_node/stats` endpoint for instance) and tune, then test again and so on.

You should start by a single index, and use the new `rollover` API to manage it , see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/indices-rollover-index.html.